# How to solve a ODE involving exponentials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve this equation analytically?

$dx /dt = (1 − e^{2t} )\cdot x − a\cdot e^t$

where $a$ is a constant

Comment: By $e^2t$ did you mean $e^{2t}$ (`e^{2t}`)?

Comment: What is the $cst$?

Comment: Use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations).

Comment: Why did the most recent edit remove cst?

Comment: @Axion004 Presumably because it was an abbreviation for constant, but looked like a constant multiplied by $t$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve $\dot{x}+P(t)x=Q(t)$, multiply both sides by the *integration factor* $R(t):=\exp\int Pdt$, which satisfies $\dot{R}=RP$, so $\frac{d}{dt}(Rx)=RQ$ and $x=R^{-1}\int Rqdt$. In this case$$P=e^{2t}-1,\,Q=-ae^t\implies R=\exp\left(\tfrac12e^{2t}-t\right),\,\int RQdt=-\tfrac12a\operatorname{Ei}\left(\tfrac12e^{2t}\right).$$Hence$$x=-\tfrac12a\exp\left(t-\tfrac12e^{2t}\right)\operatorname{Ei}\left(\tfrac12e^{2t}\right)+C\operatorname{Ei}\left(\tfrac12e^{2t}\right).$$